# Android listview not load one by one item is load completely when complete data download?

Tags: android, android-listview

i have one flight list in that i am fetchin the data using JSON PARSING and i am done this but my problem is this data show when all the textview item is loaded but i want one row item is fetch than is load after first item load is load the second item one by one not directly show the all item

I want this here you can see image what is want to do with listview
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

BUT THIS IS NOT WORK THIS IS SHOW ME RESULT DIRECTLY LIKE THIS IMAGE
[image]
here i put my code for

> HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home);

            new FlightListBack().execute("");
        }
public class FlightListBack extends AsyncTask<String,ArrayList< HashMap<String,String>> , ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>>
{

    ArrayList<String> airportList = new ArrayList<String>();
    JsonParser jparser= new JsonParser();
    List<String> spinnercityList= new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<String> spinnerAirportNameList= new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray  sjairport;



    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(
            String... params) {



                 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> flightList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            String flighturl = "http://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/json/airport/status/JFK/dep/2012/12/21/5?appId=4dde11f5&appKey=6b80a6ed5d82c8f0b&utc=false&numHours=6";
                String jsonstringfunction=jparser.getJSONFromUrl(flighturl);


                    try
                    {

                            JSONObject jobject= new JSONObject(jsonstringfunction); 
                            JSONObject appendix = jobject.getJSONObject(TAG_APPENDIX);              Log.e("JOBJECT ","APPENDIX-->"+appendix.length());

                            // Airlines Array For Getting Airlines Name
                            JSONArray  jairlines=appendix.getJSONArray(TAG_AIRLINES);               Log.e("JSONARRAY","AIRLINES"+jairlines.length());



                            // Airport Array For Getting Airport Name
                            JSONArray  jairport=appendix.getJSONArray(TAG_AIRPORT);                 Log.e("JSONARRAY","AIRPORT"+jairport.length());

                            // Flightstatuses Array For Getting INFO
                            JSONArray jflightstatuses=jobject.getJSONArray(TAG_FLIGHTSTATUSES);     Log.e("JSONARRAY","FLIGHTSTATUSES"+jflightstatuses.length());

                            int i;
                            int j;
                            int k;
                            int m;
                            int n;


                            //****************************** Flightstatuses Array *****************************
                            for(i=0;i<jflightstatuses.length();i++)
                            {

                                // creating new HashMap
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                                arrivalairportfscode=jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).get(TAG_ARRIVALAIRPORTFSCODE).toString();     //  Log.e("ArrivalAirportFsCode","AirportFSCode"+arrivalairportfscode);
                                carrierfscode=jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).get(TAG_CARRIERFSCODE).toString(); 
                                flightnumber=jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).get(TAG_FLIGHTNUMBER).toString();


                                //****************************** Airport Array *****************************
                                // Comparing ArrivalAirportFsCode For Finding The City Name
                                for(j=0;j<jairport.length();j++)
                                {
                                    // Airport Fs Code from AirportArray
                                    airportfs=jairport.getJSONObject(j).get(TAG_AIRPORTFS).toString(); //   Log.e("AIRPORT","FS"+airportfs);

                                    // Compare ArrivalAirport FsCode and Airport Fs Code For Finding City Name
                                    if(arrivalairportfscode.equalsIgnoreCase(airportfs))
                                    {   
                                        // City Name From Airport Array
                                        city=jairport.getJSONObject(j).get(TAG_AIRPORTCITY).toString();     //Log.e("Airport City","City-->"+city);
                                        destination="( "+arrivalairportfscode+" ) "+city;       //Log.e("Destination City","city"+destination);
                                        flight=carrierfscode+" "+flightnumber;

                                    }
                                }   // airport for loop complete

                                map.put(TAG_MDESTINATION, destination);
                                map.put(TAG_MFLIGHT,flight);
                                //*******************************************************************************

                                //****************************** Airlines Array *****************************

                                // Comparing CarriersFsCode To AirlinesArrayfs for Finding The Airlines Names 
                                for(k=0;k<jairlines.length();k++)
                                {

                                    // Airport Fs Code from AirportArray
                                    airlinesfs=jairlines.getJSONObject(k).get(TAG_AIRLINESFS).toString();   //Log.e("AIRLINES","FS"+airlinesfs);

                                    // Compare ArrivalAirport FsCode and Airport Fs Code For Finding City Name
                                    if(carrierfscode.equalsIgnoreCase(airlinesfs))
                                    {   
                                        // Airlines Name From Airlines Array
                                        airlinesname=jairlines.getJSONObject(k).get(TAG_AIRLINENAME).toString();        //Log.e("AIRLINES NAME","NAME"+airlinesname);
                                        Log.e("--"+flight,"--"+airlinesname);

                                    }

                                } // airlines for loop complete
                                map.put(TAG_MAIRLINE,airlinesname);

                                JSONObject joperationaltimes=jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(TAG_OPERATIONALTIMES);
                                Log.e("Operational times","-->"+joperationaltimes);

                                // Schedule Time 

                                JSONObject jschedulegatedeparture =new JSONObject();
                                JSONObject jestimateddeparture =new JSONObject();

                                for(m=0;m<joperationaltimes.length();m++)
                                {   
                                    if(joperationaltimes.has(TAG_SCHEDULEDGATEDEPARTURE))
                                    {   

                                           jschedulegatedeparture=joperationaltimes.getJSONObject(TAG_SCHEDULEDGATEDEPARTURE);
                                           schedule=jschedulegatedeparture.getString(TAG_SCHEDULEDATELOCAL).toString();
                                           schedule=schedule.substring(11);

                                           Log.e("Before convert","Time"+schedule);

                                           DateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                                           Date d = f1.parse(schedule);
                                           DateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
                                           schedule=f2.format(d).toLowerCase(); // "12:18am"

                                           Log.e("After convert","Time"+schedule);
                                         //  jestimateddeparture=joperationaltimes.getJSONObject(TAG_ACTUALGATEDEPARTURE);
                                         //  actual=jestimateddeparture.getString(TAG_ACTUALDATELOCAL).toString();
                                         //  actual=actual.substring(11);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                         schedule="Not Available";
                                    }

                                }
                                map.put(TAG_MSCHEDULE, schedule);

                                //Log.e("ScheduleGatedtime",""+jschedulegatedeparture);
                                //Log.e("Schedule Time","Work"+schedule);
                                //Log.e("ActualGatedtime",""+jestimateddeparture);
                                //Log.e("Actual Time","Work"+actual);

                                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                                // AIRPORT RESOURCES OBJECT fOR getting departure terminal and departure gate

                                if(jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).has(TAG_AIRPORTRESOURCES))
                                {   

                                JSONObject airportresources=jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject(TAG_AIRPORTRESOURCES);
                                Log.e("airportresources","--->"+airportresources);

                                    if(airportresources.has(TAG_DEPARTURETERMINAL))
                                    {
                                        departureterminal=airportresources.get(TAG_DEPARTURETERMINAL).toString();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        departureterminal=""; 

                                    }

                                    if(airportresources.has(TAG_DEPARTUREGATE))
                                    {
                                        departuregate=airportresources.get(TAG_DEPARTUREGATE).toString();

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        departuregate="";
                                    }
                                    terminal="T-"+departureterminal+" ";
                                    gate=departuregate;
                                    terminalgate=terminal+gate;
                                    Log.e("Terminal Gate","-->"+terminal+gate);

                                    map.put(TAG_MTERMINALGATE,terminalgate);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    terminalgate="Not Available";
                                    map.put(TAG_MTERMINALGATE,terminalgate);
                                }



                                    status=jflightstatuses.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_STATUS).toString();
                                    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
                                    {
                                        status="Scheduled";
                                    }
                                    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))
                                    {
                                        status="Landed";
                                    }
                                    map.put(TAG_MFSTATUS, status);



                            flightList.add(map);

                            Log.e("FlightList","work"+flightList);

                            }   


                    }           
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return flightList;

            }


protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> flightList )
{
```

}

```
  }
```

> CustomListAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private ArrayList<YourListRowObject> listItems;

public CustomListAdapter (Context context) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listItems = new ArrayList<YourListRowObject>();
}

public void addItem(YourListRowObject row) {
    listItems.add(row);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textdestination = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textdestination);
        holder.textflight=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textflight);
        holder.textairline=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textairline);
        holder.textschedule=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textschedule);
        holder.texttermgate=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.texttermgate);
        holder.textstatus=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textstatus);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.textdestination.setText((listItems.get(position)).getMdestination());
    holder.textflight.setText((listItems.get(position)).getMflight());
    holder.textairline.setText((listItems.get(position)).getMairline());
    holder.textschedule.setText((listItems.get(position)).getMschedule());
    holder.texttermgate.setText((listItems.get(position)).getMtermgate());
    holder.textstatus.setText((listItems.get(position)).getMstatus());
    return convertView;
}

public int getCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listItems.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}   

private class ViewHolder{
// add here views, which are defined in `list_row Layout`
    TextView textdestination;
    TextView textairline;
    TextView textschedule;
    TextView texttermgate;
    TextView textstatus; 
    TextView textflight;

}

//contains data, which u get from server in json format. add here your fields
public class YourListRowObject{

public String mdestination;
public String mflight;
public String mairline;
public String mschedule;
public String mtermgate;
public String mstatus;
public String getMdestination() {
    return mdestination;
}
public void setMdestination(String mdestination) {
    this.mdestination = mdestination;
}
public String getMflight() {
    return mflight;
}
public void setMflight(String mflight) {
    this.mflight = mflight;
}
public String getMairline() {
    return mairline;
}
public void setMairline(String mairline) {
    this.mairline = mairline;
}
public String getMschedule() {
    return mschedule;
}
public void setMschedule(String mschedule) {
    this.mschedule = mschedule;
}
public String getMtermgate() {
    return mtermgate;
}
public void setMtermgate(String mtermgate) {
    this.mtermgate = mtermgate;
}
public String getMstatus() {
    return mstatus;
}
public void setMstatus(String mstatus) {
    this.mstatus = mstatus;
}



}

}
```

Comment: Do you know lazy adapter concept for list view item loading ?? that will help you a lot.

Comment: i wiil try this link but still is display listview after complete data is load fot text listview [http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/]

Answer (score 2):

```
    // initialize adapter in `onCreate()`
    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(context);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

create **`CustomListAdapter`**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private ArrayList<YourListRowObject> listItems;

public CustomListAdapter (Context context) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    listItems = new ArrayList<YourListRowObject>();
}

public void addItem(YourListRowObject row) {
    listItems.add(row);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText((listItems.get(position)).stringValue);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}   

private class ViewHolder{
// add here views, which are defined in `list_row Layout`
    public TextView text;
}
}

// contains data, which u get from server in json format. add here your fields
public class YourListRowObject{

   public String stringValue;
}
```

`list_row` Layout - define this layout, which represents `ListView` row

In `doInBackground()`

```
// get json object from server
// parse json object into YourListRowObject

adapter.addItem(yourListRowObject); // add this object to adapter
```

Comment: you have any link for this type example so i can understatnd more for this

Comment: YourListRowObject - rename please ))) it was just example, idea. It's ok now, but I can't see where are you creating CustomListAdapter in your Home activity. Write this in onCreate(): CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(context);
    setListAdapter(adapter);     In doInBackground() - get JSON object from server and add this object to adapter